# Missing one Necessary Argument: dataSource

Tags: datasource, typeorm

this is my package json

```
  "scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"dev:server": "ts-node-dev --inspect --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules src/server.ts",
"typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

},

this is my ormconfig.json

```
{
"type": "postgres",
"host": "localhost",
"port": 5432,
"username": "test",
"password": "test",
"database": "gostack_gobarber",
"migrations": [
    "./src/database/migrations/*.ts"
],
"cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
}
```

}

`yarn typeorm migration:create - CreateAppointments` i created this files, put my new table here

`yarn typeorm migration:run` Now i have to execute this but, my terminal comes with a error saying that i need dataSource file. Please someone help me, i tryed some things that i found here but no sucess. if you can explain in details whats i should do

Comment: ormconfig.json is deprecated. You need to create a datasource file. Then you can run commands adding "-d path/to/datasource.ts".

Answer (score 0):

***[SOLVED]***
[ormconfig is no longer supported after version 0.3.0](https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1:%7E:text=drop%20ormconfig%20support)

## Solution

**In a nutshell:** TypeORM is expecting to find a `DataSource()` instance.

### How to do this?

#### Short answer

```js
// datasource.ts
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
const ormConfig = { /* Add your config here */ };
export default new DataSource(OrmConfig);
```

Then use the `-d` in the TypeORM command to specify the path to the datasource.

*Example:* `typeorm migration:generate path/to/Migration -d path/to/datasource`

#### Long answer

```js
// orm.config.ts

import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

// Note: use your corresponding Database config
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';

// General DB connection config
const ormConfig: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(<string>process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['path/to/entities'],
  migrations: ['path/to/migrations'],
  synchronize: false,
  ssl: true,
};

export default new DataSource(ormConfig);
```

`package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "migration:create": "typeorm migration:create ./path/to/migration",
    "migration:generate": "typeorm migration:generate -d ./path/to/datasource ./path/to/migration",
    "migration:run": "typeorm migration:run -d ./path/to/datasource"
  },
```